# TinyMCE and WIRIS Plugin Error - Failed to load plugin: tiny_mce_wiris

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tinymce

I am using TinyMCE on Rails 5 and I am adding on the [WIRIS plugin](http://www.wiris.com/en/plugins/docs/tinymce) to enable users to insert mathematical equations. I've followed all the steps on the website to install the plugin, but my editor shows this error:

Failed to load plugin: tiny_mce_wiris from url http://localhost:3000/assets/tinymce/plugins/tiny_mce_wiris/plugin.js

My script at application.html.erb looks like the following:

```
<script>
    tinymce.init({
        selector: ".tinymce",
        plugins: "tiny_mce_wiris"
    });
</script>
```

And my editor in one of my views, show.html.erb, looks like this:

```
<%= form_for ([@question, @question.answers.build]) do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_area :answercontent, :class => "tinymce", :rows => 10, :cols => 90 %> 
  <!-- Before this I had <%= tinymce %> to initialize tinyMCE, and the editor worked well. Now that I have the script I deleted it. -->
  <%= f.submit "Submit", class: "btn btn-default" %>
<% end %>
```

And in my Assets folder, I have a tinymce directory with the tiny_mce_wiris plugin. I've also installed the gem.

My wiris directory is at:

/app/assets/tinymce/plugins/tiny_mce_wiris (which is the same as the directory path shown in the error)

I've looked up resources and gone through the support on the Wiris page, but I cannot seem to find anyone who has had a similar problem.

Thanks!

+) I have integrated TinyMCE through the [Rails Integration for TinyMCE](https://github.com/spohlenz/tinymce-rails) (which uses the Rails asset pipeline), but the config method for plugins is the same, so I'm not sure if this is causing the problem. I've tried adding 'tiny_mce_wiris' to the config/tinymce.yml file under plugins, but this also didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Rails.application.config.assets.precompile` is where you want to add `tiny_mce_wiris.js`, the tinymce plugin loader won't do that bit for you.
The file you want to look into is `config/initializers/assets.rb`, the [guide](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#precompiling-assets) isn't elaborating on the topic, but it's there.

Comment: I have added this line to my `config/initializers/assets.rb` but it is not working.

`Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( tiny_mce_wiris.js )`

Comment: Can you run this on the rails console? `pp Rails.application.config.assets.precompile` just to make sure you didn't overwrite the precompile later on.